# Regex to match custom markdown syntax

Tags: regex

I want to match the following with multiple capture groups:

```
Definition 1
: This is the definition text that described the term. Can have markdown formatting and
multiple lines.
Definition 2
: This is the definition text with **markdown**.`code`
```

I also want to replace it with the following text (HTML definition list):

```
<dl>
    <dt>Definition 1</dt>
    <dd>This is the definition text that described the term. Can have markdown formatting and
multiple lines.</dd>
    <dt>Definition 1</dt>
    <dd>This is the definition text with **markdown**.`code`</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: No.  You should be using an XML parser for handling that HTML, regex is not the right tool for this.  But what are you trying actually capture here, the definition titles or the bodies?

Comment: I changed the syntax to follow markdown convention. I want to capture each definition term and its text in a match, and each match should have two capture groups such taht I can generate the HTML structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in two steps:

#### 1. Insert the `dt` and `dd` tags

Perform a search with:

```
(.*)\R: ((?:.+(?:\R|$))*?)(?=\R|.*\R:|$)/g
```

and substitute by:

```
<dt>$1</dt>\n<dd>$2</dd>\n
```

See [regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/pD2sU1/3).

#### 2. Add the `dl` tags

Use the result of the previous substitution and perform the following search:

```
/(<dt>.*?<\/dd>(?!\s*<dt>))/gs
```

and substitute by:

```
<dl>\n$1\n</dl>
```

See [regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/pD2sU1/2).

#### Remarks

If the `\R` escape is not supported, use `\n` instead.
The back-references `$1`, `$2` might need to be changed to `\1`, `\2` depending on your regex engine.

Comment: That's the issue, wrapping each block of definition items in `<dl>` tags. How do you determine the start and end of the definition list? There must be a way to accomplish this in the same regular expression.
Great solution though so far.
The other issue is that the second group should stop capturing anything after a blank line. ( I updated the test case to reflect a real use case)
[Regex Tester](https://regex101.com/r/hV9eU8/3)

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do this with one regex, as you have two levels of substitution, where one (`dt`  + `dd`) can occur more often than the other (`dl`). I have updated my answer with a 2-step approach.

Comment: Awesome answer! Incredible use of regular expressions !

Comment: This is perfectly legitimate question with a great answer. "closed as too broad"